# Dialogflow can't handle shortforms for @sys.date

Tags: dialogflow-es

So I am making a bot that tells the user my shop's operating hours. The code works but the problem is, Dialogflow can't seem to recognize shortforms like 'next sat', 'on mon', 'ltr', 'tmr'. I tried using custom entities but I can't tell Dialogflow to recognize the custom entity as a system parameter like @sys.date, and I'm having trouble extracting the dates from phrases like these. I could hard code it, for example

```
var date  = new Date();
var short = agent.parameters.shortform;
var day   = date.getDay();
if (short == 'tmr'){
  if(day==6){day=0;}else{day+=1;}
}
```

but if I do this, I'd have to take into account every possible shortform my user can write and write code for it, including every day of the week, every other shortform like nxt, ltr, hrs, mins. Is there an easier way?

Comment: Have you tried to create a separate intent matching the short-forms values, prompting the user to be more specific on entering the date parameter `@sys.date`? this would simplify a lot of things here.

Comment: I think you could save yourself a lot of trouble by just letting this go into a fallback intent and inform the user to use longer formats. This way you dont have to code for every option and map every option back to a longer value when you want to deal with it in code.

Comment: Yeah, I'll do that for now. Thank you.

Comment: @ilnspirev, Do you have any progress implementing the suggested solutions?

Comment: Yes, I just moved everything to a fallback intent. Isn't an ideal result, but I guess I'm happy enough with it.